# Añadir div class antes o después de otro div class con javascript

Tags: javascript

He buscado durante horas y no encuentro una solución. Si pueden Ayudarme por favor.
Quiero insertar un *`<div class="nuevo"></div>`* justo encima de todos los *div class=label*  al cargar el DOM, estos div están dentro de un elemento padre llamado *`<div class="verse">`*. Necesito usar solo javascript, aparecen 10 div aproximadamente en el DOM.

**Algo así necesito**

**De esto:**
`<div class="verse">`
  **`<div class="label">contenido</div>`**
`</div>`

**A esto:**

`<div class="verse">`
  *`<div class="nuevo">contenido nuevo</div>`*
  *`<div class="label">contenido</div>`*
`</div>`

así ocurra en todos los elementos  que son hijos de *verse* en el DOM.

**Intenté con esto**, pero me inserta el elemento dentro de otros *div label*, que no son elementos hijos de *div verse*, pero lo necesito es solo en los elementos que son hijos de ***verse***, justo encima del *`<div class="label">`*.

```
const labels =  document.querySelectorAll('.label');

labels.forEach((item) => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "nuevo");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "New Div";
  const parent = item.parentNode;
  parent.insertBefore(newDiv, item);
});
<div class="verse">
    <div class="label">contenido</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `document` tiene un método para esto: [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Todos los elementos en `html` tienen un elemento padre así sea el `<body>` o el `<html>`. Lo que puedes hacer es algo como:

```js
const labels =  document.querySelectorAll('.label');

labels.forEach((item) => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "nuevo");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "New Div";
  const parent = item.parentNode;
  parent.insertBefore(newDiv, item);
});
```

Comment: es cierto hay un elemento padre que lo clasifica, el elemento es span class="verse".  osea label está dentro de la clase verse

Comment: ya he aclarado mejor la pregunta, cabe destacar que tu código me funciona bien, pero me añade el div dentro de otros que no deseo, esto se debe que no me expliqué bien con respecto al elemento padre que se llama verse

Comment: Ésta respuesta es correcta desde mi punto de vista. Da igual como se llame el parent, lo descubrirá igual.  Si necesitas que solo ocurra dentro del div con clase verse debes poner un condicional dentro del bucle que lo compruebe.

Comment: @AmilcarMunoz si, me funciona muy bien, pero no se como colocar el condicional con el elemento padre, estoy intentando pero no me da. perdón es que soy nuevo en JavaScript.

Comment: @CarlosColina Prueba poniendo `if(parent.classList.contains("verse")) {` después de la asignación de la constante **parent** y dentro de ese condicional le pones la siguiente línea: `parent.insertBefore(newDiv, item);` y luego cierras el condicional, claro, con la llave de cierre `}`

Comment: Cuando ya lo tengas no vuelvas a cambiar la pregunta, pues esta respuesta ya era correcta para tu primera pregunta y deberías aceptarla. Si luego tienes más casos haz nuevas preguntas. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo.